# Free after assigning value for field in global structure

Tags: c, scope, free

Here is small C program that I am trying to understand:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct dm_user_params_t {
    int x;
} dm_user_params;

dm_user_params xx;

void set_user_params(dm_user_params *yy) {
    xx.x = yy->x;
}

int main() {
    dm_user_params xx;
    dm_user_params *yy;
    yy = malloc(sizeof(dm_user_params));
    yy->x = 217;
    set_user_params(yy);
    free(yy);
    printf("2 %d" , xx.x);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
537340672
```

What should I do, so that value in `xx.x` should persist ?

Is reference is copied instead of value when I do `xx.x = yy->x` ? How to verify this ?

Comment: `xx.x` was never initialised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local variable `xx` is shadowing the global identical declaration (bearing the exact type & name)

`set_user_params` changes the global `xx`

Fix 1: remove the local variable. Also:

```
void set_user_params(dm_user_params *yy) {
    xx.x = yy->x;
}
```

could be written:

```
void set_user_params(const dm_user_params *yy) {
    xx = *yy;
}
```

so when you add more fields the `set_user_params` doesn't need to be updated.

Fix 2: remove the global variable and change prototype as is:

```
void set_user_params(dm_user_params *dest, const dm_user_params *src) {
    *dest= *src;
}
```

then call like this `set_user_params(&xx,yy);`

Comment: Thanks, I realized I have overriding definition in main after posting question.  As I have some santity checks per field of structure(structure has multiple fields), I cant directly do fix you suggested.Is assignment `xx.x = yy->x` safe, if have static global `xx` and set_user_params is called from some another c file ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with `yy` or the `free` call.

Instead it's because you have *two* independent variables named `xx`. One is a global variable that the `set_user_params` function will use. The other is a *local* variable which the `printf` function will use. The local variable have not been initialized, so the value of it will be *indeterminate*.

The solution is to *either* remove the local variable. *Or* remove the global variable and pass a pointer to the local variable as an extra argument to the `set_user_params` function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, the global `xx` outside `main()` is shadowed by the inner `xx` in `main()`.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.2.1, *Scopes of identifiers*, (*emphasis mine*)

> [...] If an identifier designates two different entities in the same name
>   space, the scopes might overlap. If so, the scope of one entity (the inner scope) will end
>   strictly before the scope of the other entity (the outer scope). **Within the inner scope, the
>   identifier designates the entity declared in the inner scope; the entity declared in the outer
>   scope is hidden (and not visible) within the inner scope.**

So, in your case,

```
 printf("2 %d" , xx.x);
```

is making an attempt to access the uninitialized local variable `xx.x`, invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

**Solution:** Remove the local variable definition of `xx` from `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
dm_user_params xx;
```

Within `main()` local variable `xx` is uninitialized whereas global `xx` is initialized . You are printing uninitialized value.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the line

```
dm_user_params xx;
```

in your main and it will work.
You have two variables `xx`, one local and one global. You set the global one in your function `set_user_params` to 217, but later in your main you print the local one, which is not initialized and will result in undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct 
{
    int x;
} dm_user_params_t;

dm_user_params_t xx;

void set_user_params(dm_user_params_t *yy) 
{
    xx.x = yy->x;
    printf("Got : %d \n",yy->x);
}

int main(void) 
{
    // dm_user_params_t xx; Note: Local object getting highest priority than global, that's why you are getting garbage value
    dm_user_params_t *yy;
    yy = malloc(sizeof(dm_user_params_t));
    yy->x = 217;
    set_user_params(yy);
    free(yy);
    printf("2 %d" , xx.x);
    return 0;
}
```